# php twitter grab retweet user info

Tags: php, mysql, twitter

i am working on a project in php.

1. When we post something on twitter, i want to grab the users who have re-tweeted my tweet and store it in my database. I want to work in php and mysql.
2. If I post a question on my tweet, i want grab the answers and save the userinfo of all the users who gave the right answer.

Any suggestions on how to get started?? Thanks :)

Comment: http://dev.twitter.com/pages/libraries#php Check out the plethora of PHP libraries for twitter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a full twitter API class that someone has built that might be useful as well.
http://brandontreb.com/the-only-twitter-api-php-class-you-will-ever-need/

UPDATED:
Here is a RESTful API service for pulling retweets of your items:
http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-REST-API-Method%3A-statuses-retweets

You can use a pre-existing class or build your own. It will most likely require cURL and XML knowledge. But if you understand PHP, you should be able to knock this out fairly quick.

Comment: I did see this but it does not have a function for retweets... retweets is the only problem for which i am not finding a solution.
Any more suggestions?

Comment: I updated the post with links to the RESTful service allowing you to pull retweets for your tweets.

Comment: Just throwing this out there, Twitter is going to loose the format of just using a username and password form, in favor of OAuth authentication, within the next month. So, at least the first link you posted will not work anymore